Unable to display a label above a dropdown list box when using Vscode webview adn Vee-validate
I have the following code in my VSCode extension making use of webview.
The first option is what I am trying to get to work. I want to display a label above the drop down listbox but no matter what, I am unable to get this to work. I haev tried various combinations of without any success.
The second option is the example provided in VsCode webview and works fine -- when used outside of Field.
<div class="dropdown-container">
        <Field name="field" as="vscode-dropdown" v-model=packageCreateParms.test>
              <vscode-option value="">--Select Create method--</vscode-option>
              <vscode-option value="Copy Forward">Copy Forward</vscode-option>
              <vscode-option value="Long">Long</vscode-option>
        </Field>
        <ErrorMessage name="field" class="error"></ErrorMessage> 
</div>

<div class="dropdown-container">
  <label for="label">Choose an option:</label>
  <vscode-dropdown id="label">
    <vscode-option>Option Label A</vscode-option>
    <vscode-option>Option Label B</vscode-option>
    <vscode-option>Option Label C</vscode-option>
  </vscode-dropdown>
</div>

